# Could somebody help me with my Code (C language)?

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C language and I have been asked to: write a whole program printing in separate lines odd numbers from `100` to `0`, and marking with "!!!" those numbers that are multiplications of `7`. 
I tried to do that but unfortunately iam printing numbers which are duplications for example (`91` and `91!!!`). How can I avoid this situation?

Here is my code maybe someone can help me with this task?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int i;
    for (i=100;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(i%2)
        {
            printf("%d\n",i);   
        } 
        if (i%7==0 && i%2!=0)
        {
            printf("%d!!!\n",i);  
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: You can avoid worrying about testing for odd numbers by using `for(i=99;i>=0;i-=2)`

Comment: HI @Jan, could you please edit your post to have well-formatted code (put all the code in a single code block including the `#include`, and then use spacing to make it read-able?)?  Thanks!

Comment: @4castle Won't then OP miss out on some multiples of 7 like 70 (provided only 1 loop has to be used)

Comment: @AditiRawat I interpreted the assignment as printing all of the odd numbers from `100` to `0` and then adding `!!!` to the numbers which are multiples of 7. Even numbers should never be printed.

Comment: This would do, I suppose. `if (i%7==0 && i%2!=0)
        {
            printf("%d!!!\n",i);  
        }  else if(i%2 != 0)
        {
            printf("%d\n",i);   
        }`

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution based on [Aditi Rawat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7714006/aditi-rawat) comment.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main ()
{
   int i;

   for (i=100; i>=0; i--)
   {
      if (i%7==0 && i%2!= 0)
      {
         printf("%d!!!\n",i);  
      }
      else
      {
         if(i%2 != 0)
           printf("%d\n",i);
      } 
   }

   return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
99
97
95
93
91!!!
89
87
85
83
81
79
77!!!
75
73
71
69
67
65
63!!!
61
59
57
55
53
51
49!!!
47
45
43
41
39
37
35!!!
33
31
29
27
25
23
21!!!
19
17
15
13
1
```